# Android - 3D "stacked" Gallery images

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

Does anyone know how to implement 3d "stacked" groups of images like that in the android photo gallery app?

I found [this link](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html) for creating a 3d carousel. Although it is a step in the right direction, it is not really what I am looking for.

[image]  [image]

Comment: The code is so huge,would take years to understand and edit it according to my needs,do you know how i can change it to use images of mediastore.album or my own pics ??and where exactly is the onclick listener setup for these images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338325/android-download-gallery-source-code?

It would be ideal to clone the source code, as Android is open source.

That is the best way to learn, but here are some code snapshots:

[Gallery 2.1r2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/Gallery.java)

[Android 2.0 Gallery app](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Camera/src/com/android/camera/ImageGallery2.java)

[From CyanogenMod, Android 2.0](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery/downloads)

[CyanogenMod, Android Gallery 2.3(Gingerbread)](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery3D)

Comment: The CyanogenMod 2.3 is a great addition. Thanks for tracking that down and adding it.

Comment: The code is so huge,would take years to understand and edit it according to my needs,do you know how i can change it to use images of mediastore.album or my own pics ??and where exactly is the onclick listener setup for these images?